# Image Processing:- Minor error issue is showing up while executing the program

Tags: python

This program is initially supposed to recognize a person's face whose photo is saved in my database. And in case it does not recognize the face it's supposed to take a screenshot automatically after a specific timer. The program is perfectly recognizing the face.

But, the problem is at taking the screenshot. I don't understand, it takes the screenshot after certain constraints but it also shows the error that(:!!- error:can't grab frame). I am understanding the problem quite to the point but it's still vague to me. I specified the problem more to the point that I am facing in the code as comments.

The code is a little bit long so please approach it patiently. If, any modifications you want to make then please do. it's my pleasure.

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import multiprocessing
    import face_recognition
    import os
    import time

    path = 'images'
    images = []
    classNames = []
    myList = os.listdir(path)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    print(myList)
    for cls in myList:
        curImg = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cls}')
        images.append(curImg)
        classNames.append(os.path.splitext(cls)[0])

    print(classNames)

    def take_screenshot():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if cap.isOpened():
            print(ret)
            print(frame)
        else:
            ret = False

        img1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        plt.imshow(img1)
        plt.title("Camera image 1")
        img_names = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(time.time())
        cv2.imwrite(img_names, frame)
        print("Screenshot taken")

        plt.xticks([])  
        plt.yticks([])
        plt.show()
        cap.release()

    def camera():
        cv2.imshow('Webcam', img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

    def countdown(u):
        while u:
            mins, sec = divmod(u, 60)
            timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, sec)
            print(timer, end = '\r')
            time.sleep(1)
            u -= 1
    def findEncodings(images):
        encodeList = []
        for img in images:
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
            encodeList.append(encode)

        return encodeList

        encodeListKnown = findEncodings(images)
        print("Encoding Complete.")

    # This part initializes the readings of real-time recordings from webcam
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        if type(img) != type(None):
            imgS = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), None, 0.25, 0.25)
            imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            faceCurFrame = face_recognition.face_locations(imgS)
            encodeCurFrame = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgS, faceCurFrame)

            for encodeFace, faceLoc in zip(encodeCurFrame, faceCurFrame):
                matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
                faceDis = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
                print(faceDis)
                matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDis)
                
                # This 'if' statement works for recognizing the face which is working perfectly.
                if matches[matchIndex]:
                    name = classNames[matchIndex].upper()
                    print(name)
                    y1, x2, y2, x1 = faceLoc
                    y1, x2, y2, x1 = y1 * 4, x2 * 4, y2 * 4, x1 * 4
                    cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                    cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y2 - 35), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
                    cv2.putText(img, name, (x1 + 6, y2 - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.9,   (255, 255, 255), 2)
              
# The 'else' statement is supposed to initialize a timer and when the timer ends, 
# it takes a screenshot. But, the 'else' statement does not trigger as soon as I turn the 
# webcam away from the face. webcam still keeps on going. But, when I try to show it the face again 
# it triggers at the first face_encoding it gets.

               # Here, as I mentioned, the program shows an error that it can't grab
               # frame(webcam does not open) but at the background it keeps on going and  
               # when the timer ends it takes screenshot also. 
                else:
                    if __name__ == '__main__': 
                        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=camera)
                        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=countdown, args=[10])

                        p1.start()
                        p2.start()

                        time.sleep(11)
                        p1.terminate()
                        p2.terminate()

                        p1.join()
                        p2.join()

                        take_screenshot()

            camera()
            time.sleep(0)

# error:-[ WARN:0@7.686] eglobal Dn:c\va-\poyptehnocnv\-oppyethon\opencnvc-pvyt-hopn\yoptenhocvn\\moduleso\pencv
# \moduvliedseo\ivoi\dseroci\oc\aspr_cm\scmafp_.cpmp sm(f.17cpp 5(21)7 5C2v)C aCpvCture_aMpStMF::gurraeb_FMrSaMmFe: 
# :vgirdaeboFiroa(mMeS MvFi)d:e ociaon('MtS MgFr)a:b  cfarna'mte .g rEarbr ofr: -r1am0e7.2 E8rr7or5: 7-17072287[ 5W7AR7N:20

# [@7 .WA7R4N0:]0 @g7.lo7b4a1l]  Dg:l\oab\aolp eDn:c\va\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\c-ap_pmystmhfo
# .nc\popp e(n1c7v5-2p)y thCovCna\popetnucrve\_mMoSdMuFl:e:sg\rvaibdFeroaimoe\ 
# svricd\ecoaipo_(mMsSmMfF.)c:p pc a(17n5'2t)  gCrvaCb afprtaumree._ MESrrMoFr: :-:1g0r7abFr2a875772
```

Comment: Also post your full error stack trace

Comment: You are taking the screenshot of the person who is not authenticated or recognised in your database then why you are capturing new frame? just pass the same frame to save from the thread

Comment: Yes, I understand your point. But, I am bound to do that because I want the camera to be activated the whole time when the timer is ongoing. Otherwise, I am only showing the capture from webcam. Does it really matter that it recognize any face or not?? If you want to make changes feel free to do it. Thank you.